# Configure Nginx to serve "/" from a directory already inside root

Tags: nginx

Inside /var/www I have my directories like this:

```
/var/www/home
/var/www/other
/var/www/other2
```

I want the root to just be /var/www so I can go to /home or /other, however I also want just / to go to /home and I can't figure that part out.

I think I could specify a root for each location like:

```
location /{ root /var/www/home; }
location /other{ root /var/www/other; }
```

But I don't want to have to change my nginx config every time I add a directory. I tried using an alias like so, but I would just get 403 forbidden and i know these pages are accessible:

```
server{
  root /var/www;
  location / {
    alias /var/www/home;
  }
}
```

Is it not possible to have the root location point to a subdirectory within the server root ?

Answer (score 0):

```
server{
    root /var/www;

    location = / {
        root /var/www/home;
    }

    location / { }
}
```

Reference:

- http://nginx.org/r/root
- http://nginx.org/r/location
- [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)
- [Understanding the Nginx Configuration Inheritance Model](http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2012/08/understanding-the-nginx-configuration-inheritance-model/)

Comment: Tried that, but the / still points at the server root, it's not using the location root.